# create webmail server like

Tags: webmail

i want to create a webmail server on ubuntu linux (GUI)or windows. please help me in this.
thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Having tried Squirrelmail and [Roundcube](http://roundcube.net/) I much prefer the latter. They're about as easy as each other to set up but Roundcube in much nicer to use.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty comprehensive:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Squirrelmail

SquirrelMail is well supported and intuitive.

Comment: This may sound slightly strange but having tried a few webmail systems (horde is really good too) I now forward all mail from my IMAP Server to Gmail so I can use their web interface. I'm still to find any webmail anywhere nearly as good as Gmail's. I still have all the control at the Mail Server level (like using Thunderbird to pick up mail or filter one particularly bad spammer or add aliases etc) but don't have any of the maintenance work for the webmail element, HTH, JR.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/). It shows step by step guide for installing mail server in linux, hope it helps. If any clarifications, feel free to ask.